# Why are my rigid body objects falling out of their moving container?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have created a lottery ball cage as it were. The cage is a passive rigid body. Inside the cage are about 200 lottery balls with rigid body active settings. The cage spins for about 20 seconds, then raises about 2 feet to the ceiling.

During the bake, all goes well. The balls roll with the cage. Here comes the issue. Halfway into the cage going up to the ceiling, half the balls decide to fall out and end up back where the cage was originally.

I am away from home and will post screenshots when I get back. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to animate the cage, set it to Active->Animated instead of Passive.

Comment: Did you get to solve this?

Comment: Apologies! So I don't know what the correlation is, but I figure it out. I literally had to delete the rigid body world and start a new rigid body world, and all worked well! I guess the first world had too many...things going on or too many settings accumulating?

Comment: Good to see you got it going.  I initially had more balls on the floor than in the barrel, lol.  The balls were too small for the cage slots so I placed an invisible and solid cylinder inside the first and parented it to the visible one. I also incremented the particles "subframe" setting a notch.
That worked so well I dropped the whole thing to the floor and still no escapees.  I learned something from your question and have upvoted it. :)

Comment: Just for everyone's edification. https://youtu.be/KbQm2cuXRE4. Came out fantastic!

Comment: It certainly did!  :)